# Macro for google sheets for all users who open to fit screen to range in a protected sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-macros

I have a select range of cells that I am using for a dashboard I want all users to view on their screen upon opening the spreadsheet.  The name of the sheet is dashboard and the range is A1:R36.  The range A1:R36 is also protect from other users editing so I am not sure if that would stop the code from working.

I have tried this macro and logged in as another user but it does not work.

```
function OnOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:R39').activatewindow.Zoom = True();
};
```

Comment: No such method in Range Class or  Google Apps Script as far as I know.

Comment: You would need to change the zoom to 75% in the editor to be able to see `A1:R36` completely (and that varies from screen to screen). However, after going over the [UI documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui), there does not seem to be a way to access the zoom level of the editor through apps script. Consider posting a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/) for it.